# Is it worth refilling these fire extinguishers or should I just throw out?

Tags: fire-extinguisher

[image: two old fire extinguishers]
[image]

please help me decide what to do with these old fire extinguishers - are they worth re-filling
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Depends if it's disposable or refillable. Many cheaper extinguishers are disposable (only) and not designed to be refillable. After that it's just math (cost of service, possibly including hydro testing, .vs. cost of replacement extinguisher.)

Comment: Also the size usually less than a few pounds it is cheaper to buy new.